# What is the best alternative IDE to Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ide

As I've only ever used Visual Studio for .NET development, I would like to expand my horizons and see what else there is on offer as an alternative to it. So what in your opinion is the best alternative to Visual Studio? Is there a viable alternative?

Comment: Sure, I love VS too, but people should always have several opportunities

Comment: I would love to see something with all the functionality of VS that I use, but 10% of the memory usage

Comment: I would love to see something with all the functionality of VS, but Open Source...

Comment: I would love to see something with all the functionality of VS, but works on Linux.  MonoDevelop is good but doesn't cut it

Comment: I would love to see something functionally equivalent to VS, but free, and using 10% of the memory, and compiling 10 times as fast, and with a cherry on top, and it should give me a back massage, and, and, and... Seriously, it's a pretty good product as it is.  Not too expensive if you are actually selling the software you produce.  Will probably pay for it after the first 10-20 sales (less if you charge more for your software).  If you are making free software, they have a free version that is actually pretty good.

Comment: Its worth tracking  [Project Rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/01/13/project-rider-a-csharp-ide/) from Jetbrains

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you're into C# and VB.Net and don't mind open source then you could use [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). It does a pretty good job!

Comment: I agree with you. Sharp Develop is the most powerfull free .NET IDE.

Comment: Agree, have used them all, but nothing close to SharpDevelop including the Xamarin Studio. It even lets me reference COM objects.

Comment: MonoDevelop also work nah!

Answer (score 24):

There are many alternatives, check this list: [Alternative IDEs to Visual Studio.NET](http://web.archive.org/web/20071217202115/http://www.dotnetcoders.com/web/Articles/ShowArticle.aspx?article=49), mirrored on Web Archive because the [original link](http://www.dotnetcoders.com/web/Articles/ShowArticle.aspx?article=49) is down.

Answer (score 12):

[vim](http://www.vim.org/)

It also helps you to [stop using your mouse](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000825.html) so much!

Comment: I love the irony in having to use your mouse to stop using your mouse ;-)

Comment: On the contrary, there is no need to use your mouse to follow my links. See http://lynx.isc.org/ or http://lifehacker.com/139495/hack-attack-mouse+less-firefox for examples.

Answer (score 8):

[Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com).

Here's an example showing code completion, taken from the Zeus homepage.

[image: example.cs open in Zeus, showing code-completion]

Comment: +1 I like the way I can import Visual Studio solution files.

Comment: Nice and fast with a good set of features.

Comment: minus 7 billion because it boast that it is "an IDE designed by programmers for programming."  NO SHIT!

Answer (score 6):

There's [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Main_Page), which I occasionally use when I want to do some light C# coding when in Linux.  It's nothing close to VS.Net, but it works for small projects.  I really don't think most of the alternatives people have listed come anywhere close to VS.Net.

Comment: Regarding coming close to Visual Studio, while nothing is as good as Visual Studio, I don't think anything comes closer to Visual Studio than SharpDevelop.

Answer (score 4):

The other great thing about [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) is the ability to translate solutions between the two big managed .NET languages VB.NET and C#. I believe it doesn't work for "websites" but it does for web application projects.

Comment: Interesting feature! I don't know if it's a reason for choosing an IDE, though, because that sounds like once-off kind of task, not the kind you would do all the time.

Answer (score 2):

As far as .net languages go, VS is hard to beat.

I have used SharpDevelop before for .net, and is overall pretty good.

For other languages like Java, Eclipse is really good, as well as some of the Eclipse variants like Aptana for web work.

Then there's always notepad...

Answer (score 1):

Try out this one: "Pao" at http://pao-ide.info . It's still in development and not up to production use but it's quite unique in features. Basically, all the language constructs, such as assemblies, types, members, statements, expressions are treated as objects and are associated with rich operation options. You can enjoy features usually seen in graphical editors, such as multiple selection, multiple copy-paste, tagging, batch operation and very powerful search capability. It takes some getting used to but eventually might increase productivity. Right now, it only supports form applications though.

Answer (score 0):

I still like [Source Insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com/) a lot, but I'm hesitant to recommend it anymore as I'm not sure anybody's still maintaining it. They released a very minor update back in March but haven't had a major release in years. And there seems to be no web community presence. It's a shame because I still like its auto-completion-friendly file open and symbol browsing panels (as well as syntax formatting) better than anything else I've ever used.

Comment: Seems to be alive again, at least according to the version numbers. Per https://www.sourceinsight.com/download/ : Version 4.0.0082 - Feb 20, 2017; and the older Version 3.5.0083 - June. 13th, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

What about WebMatrix: http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/ ?

Comment: webmatrix is mainly for web development, and its damn good

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse** has several C# plugins, the best I've found to date is **[Emonic](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/)** . You can target .NET or Mono with the help of it. Both Eclipse and Emonic are open source.

Answer (score -1):

For .NET development, VS2008 is the best but if you want to check for another best IDE, **[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)** probably the best after VS if you are rating it among the IDEs, ofcourse you cant do .NET development in Eclipse though

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to try Java, I believe NetBeans is a very, very good IDE. However, for .NET, sure there are alternative IDEs but I don't think it makes much sense to use them unless you are developing on an Open Source platform, in which case SharpDevelop is a good choice and is reasonably mature.