# ASP.NET Editors

Tags: asp.net, text-editor

I'm trying to get something out of VS. Any recommendations for a simple, yet powerful text editor that has syntax support for asp.net and a nice FTP client built in?

Comment: What are you trying to get out of VS?  Do you mean you don't want to use VS any more?

Comment: you can use VS web developer , it's free,  if you don't like VS's price

Answer (score 2):

Think [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) will be your choice =)

or [this](http://www.aptana.org/) one for Web

Comment: I agree, one of the best editor's on the market and it's free.

Comment: Has it nice FTP client built in?;)

Comment: Yepp, as it has a lot of plugins it has nice FTP client among them. By the way it is included to default download.

Answer (score 0):

[Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/Expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx) will make ASP.NET web sites and has FTP built in.

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop:

http://monodevelop.com/

Its really well done

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple these are off the top of my head:

- [SharpDevelp](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)
- [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/)

Also looks like this has been asked before:

[What is the best alternative IDE to Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310735/what-is-the-best-alternative-ide-to-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about FTP support, but I love using [TextPad](http://textpad.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/) editor has a syntax highlighter that is fully configurable and it also can do seamless *ftp/sftp* editing.