# alternative to visual studio 2010

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Is there any alternative to visual studio 2010 for develop with .net 4.0?

thanks

Comment: No. Is there any reason?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310735/what-is-the-best-alternative-ide-to-visual-studio-2008

Comment: If price is the concern, you can always use the free Visual Studio 2010 Express versions.  Are you wanting to develop .net 4.0 from Linux or MacOS?

Comment: Been having problems with your GPU too, huh? It gives me a black screen about 3 or 4 times a week.

Answer (score 10):

Considering that .NET 4.0 only just came out (at the same time as VS 2010) I would hazard a guess at "No". :)

In general, Visual Studio is by far the best IDE I've ever used. Nothing else even comes close.

Comment: I guess you have not tried any of the java IDEs out there. They are

1. much more stable

2. much faster

3. have 10x superior code refactoring facilities

4. Use just about 150-200MB in disk for basic versions, very easy to install uninstall

I am also looking for alternatives for Visual studio. But there is no "feature complete" alternative yet. Too bad i have to use VS. I wish InetlliJ one day release an IDEA.NET

Answer (score 9):

You can use [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/Opensource/SD/) to develop .NET projects, including .NET version 4.0. SharpDevelop 4.0 final has been released 06/2011. (<strike>though the support for 4.0 is still in beta status AFAIK.</strike>)

Comment: Looking at the recent changes of SharpDevelop (http://web.archive.org/web/20071215094120/www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Changes.aspx), they didn't do anything since 2007. News History (http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/NewsHistory.aspx) stopped 2005. Is this an old page or is the project dead?

Comment: The project isn't dead. Maybe they don't update that pages. Here is a forum thread about the SharpDevelop 4.0 Beta 1 Preview: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/10832.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link. Indeed, the project isn't dead. it's always bad to not update a web site.

Comment: @Stefan: you looked at an old copy of the website at archive.org. The current website http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Changes.aspx lists all releases.

Comment: @Daniel: Yeah, this had been linked by another stackoverflow question, I didn't recognize it. Silly me.

Answer (score 7):

Notepad and .net 4.0 compiler :-)

Comment: I would say Notepad++, but +1 for hammer n nails approach.

Answer (score 4):

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) is really catching up. It is not a 100% replacement of VS, because it is based on Mono. The IDE is starting to be really good (GUI designer, debugger, test framework, web and IPhone stuff etc. etc.). Supports .NET 3.5 for now.

Answer (score 1):

The visual studio platform crashes frequeltly, Several times a day, especially when debugging.
I use sharpdevelop when debugging. It does not have all the features of VS, but it doesn't crash.

Comment: Sounds like you need a more stable computer. I've been using VS2010 for years and its never crashed on me.

Comment: How have you been using it "for years"?  It was only released 1 year ago.  I have found it to be much more stable than previous versions, but I have had it crash.  I find that VS tends to crash when writing VB.Net code, but is much more stable with C#

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do your development in the cloud, check out www.coderun.com