# Alternate .NET development tools other than Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [alternative to visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697025/alternative-to-visual-studio-2010)

I was wondering if there are any other tools that can be used to develop C#.NET application (like winodws forms and webforms) just like Visual Studio.

Are there any applications that are similar to Visual Studio for .NET application development?

Comment: Are you asking for strickly IDEs or plugins or what?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180939/net-must-have-development-tools

Answer (score 4):

On Windows you could use [SharpDevelop](http://sharpdevelop.net/opensource/sd/).  It works for C#, VB.NET, F#, and Boo.  It also has a WinForms and WPF designer surface.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).